# finding frequency min and max of an array of measurements

Tags: graph, mathematical-optimization, discrete-mathematics

I have an array of measurements which look similiar to an ECG.

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4c/Normal_ECG_2.svg/660px-Normal_ECG_2.svg.png

I need to make some function that can find the frequency, min and max of such a graph. It isn't actually an ECG so some specific techniques for an ECG wouldn't work.

I have no experience in such data processen so any pointers are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your level of experience with software and signal processing, there are a number of possible ways to go about this, including MATLAB, python libraries, etc.  You haven't specified whether you need to examine an existing dataset, or if you need to build a system for reading an incoming signal, so I will assume the former.

I recommend applying a [Fast Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform), which is a widely used method for transforming the discrete data set you have into the frequency domain.  Then, finding the frequency of the beat you're attempting to measure is as simple as finding a peak within a frequency range that makes sense.  In MATLAB, these functions are called [fft](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html) and [findpeak](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html).

Comment: It actually is live data. My math is rather weak so I will have to dive into some khan academy videos! Thx for your suggestion!